# Misleading tool tips on Meta

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, meta, voting

Votes on Meta often [signify](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1894/closing-back-doors-to-deleted-content-for-halachic-reasons/1895?noredirect=1#comment6437_1895) agreement/disagreement on [content](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/563/3073) and not research-usefulness-clarity. Shouldn't the tool tips match that, so newbies like me won't get confused? I suggest "I support the idea of this question"/"I oppose the idea of this question".

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75049/166155

Comment: @DoubleAA Right, and loads of related questions there. The two agreeing answers are +84✓ and +23, and the disagreeing one is –40. Since the votes on Meta signify agreement, the |status-decline| puzzles me.

Comment: Pay attention to who wrote the -40 answer.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in comments above, [the same proposal has been made, and has had many, many eyes on it for quite some time, on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75049). Please see there for more information and future updates.

I'm posting this here just to get this question off of the list of unanswered questions here.